# Forcing specific characteristics for a series of parameters

Tags: java, class, object, types, parameters

I'm creating a Java class with a constructor that accepts a number of parameters. Out of these parameters, a selection have the exact same restriction:

1. They can be just null.
2. They can have a single item (in this case, an object I've called 'Link' for this example, but can also be a number of other objects), but that must then be embedded in an ArrayList to simplify everything later.
3. They can be an ArrayList of a specific type (Links in this example).

My code so far (ignoring the Link class that is simply "public class Link"):

```
public class Item {
    public ArrayList<Link> Links;
    public String OtherThing;
    public Item(Object Links, String OtherThing) {
        this.Sources = prepareArrayList(Links, Link);
        this.OtherThing = OtherThing;
    }
    public Item() {}
    private ArrayList prepareArrayList(Object Object, Object Type) {
        if(Type.isInstance(Object)) {
            return new ArrayList<Type>(Arrays.asList((Type) Object));
        } else if (Object instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
            if(!((ArrayList<?>) Object).isEmpty()) {
                if(Type.isInstance(((ArrayList<?>) Object).get(0))) {
                    return (ArrayList<Type>) Object;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Currently this doesn't even get as far as compilation, because I can't pass the Type parameter as the ArrayList's type. After doing a lot of research, it's become clear I'm doing something very wrong.

If I do it for a single type, say, Link, it works just fine (see below), but I need it to work for every type, of which I've got about eight, making it tricky to run this logic on each one.

```
 private ArrayList prepareArrayList(Object Object) {
        if(Link.isInstance(Object)) {
            return new ArrayList<Link>(Arrays.asList((Link) Object));
        } else if (Object instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
            if(!((ArrayList<?>) Object).isEmpty()) {
                if(Link.isInstance(((ArrayList<?>) Object).get(0))) {
                    return (ArrayList<Link>) Object;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

That works just fine. Could it be possible I need to use some kind of interface or another class to get this working? Possibly a custom ArrayList extension? Thank you.

Comment: If you are working just with `Link`, why are you using `Object` instead of just `Link` or `List<Link>`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Sorry, I wrote my question wrong, I'll correct it now. There are different types aside from Link being used. I had it working perfectly the way you mentioned, but then I had to repeat it about 8 times for different objects besides Link.

Comment: OK, so why not make `Item` generic? Note that if you're storing things in an `Array<Link>` inside it, you won't be able to put anything other than `Link` in it.

Comment: Well, that's why I was using a function for that, there's also other parameters like strings. I've quickly updated the main code.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mix the fact that your internal implementation requires an `ArrayList` with the parameter types. Bottom line, your constructor(s) should be able to receive one or more `Link`s. You could provide a `Collection<Link>` constructor and/or a `Link...` constructor and create the `ArrayList` yourself:

```
public Item(Collection<Link> links) {
    this.sources = new ArrayList(links);
}

public Item(Link... links) {
    this(Arrays.asList(links));
}
```

Comment: This would work great for if I just had the one parameter. Problem is I've got several different parameters that can all alternate between one Link, an ArrayList of Links, and null. I'm not sure this technique would work - well, it would, for that, but it wouldn't work very well.

Comment: @Furza If you have many parameters, then you should consider the Builder pattern rather than trying to pass them to the constructor. That would allow you to have each of them in single/varargs/collection forms.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'm looking at that now, actually!